# How to check for contact social accounts in IOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, ios9

I know you can do something like this if you want to set a social account:

```
let facebookProfile = CNLabeledValue(label: "Facebook", value: CNSocialProfile(urlString: "https://www.facebook.com/appsfoundation", username: "AppsFoundation", userIdentifier: "appsfoundation", service: CNSocialProfileServiceFacebook))

let twitterProfile = CNLabeledValue(label: "Twitter", value: CNSocialProfile(urlString: "https://twitter.com/AppsFoundation", username: "AppsFoundation", userIdentifier: "appsfoundation", service: CNSocialProfileServiceTwitter))

newContact.socialProfiles = [facebookProfile, twitterProfile]
```

But how do you actually check if a contact has any social profiles and how to retrieve them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have to use the `value` property:

```
for i in 0..<contact.socialProfiles.count {
    if (contact.socialProfiles[i].value as! CNSocialProfile).service == CNSocialProfileServiceFacebook {
    facebookAccount.text = (contact.socialProfiles[i].value as! CNSocialProfile).username

    } else {
       facebookAccount.text = ""
    }

    if (contact.socialProfiles[i].value as! CNSocialProfile).service == CNSocialProfileServiceTwitter {
    twitterAccount.text = (contact.socialProfiles[i].value as! CNSocialProfile).username
    } else {
       twitterAccount.text = ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

//This Fetches all the values os SocialProfile of different accounts like twitter, facebook etc

```
for (CNLabeledValue<CNSocialProfile*>* labeledValue in contact.socialProfiles)
{

      NSString * socialProfileurlString = labeledValue.value.urlString;
      NSLog(@"socialProfileurlString = %@",socialProfileurlString);

      NSString *socialProfileUsername = labeledValue.value.username;
      NSLog(@"socialProfileUsername = %@",socialProfileUsername);

      NSString *socialProfileUserIdentifier = labeledValue.value.userIdentifier;
      NSLog(@"socialProfileUserIdentifier = %@",socialProfileUserIdentifier);

      NSString *socialProfileUserService = labeledValue.value.service;
      NSLog(@"socialProfileUserService = %@",socialProfileUserService);

}
```